# On hover change span:before and h3

Tags: html, css

So it's time to enlist the help of people smarter than myself. What I'm trying to do is get CSS hover effects to work on multiple elements.

Code for example:

```
<div class="box alt">
    <div class="row uniform">
        <section class="4u 6u(medium) 12u$(xsmall)">
            <span class="icon alt major fa-sliders"></span>
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the cursor hovers over section, I want to change the span:before and h3:

```
cursor: pointer;
color: #00AEEF;
text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #00AEEF, -1px 0 0 #00AEEF, 0 1px 0 #00AEEF, 0 -1px 0 #00AEEF;
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Bg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/0vkn4fu4/)

```
.row section:hover span:before,
.row section:hover h3 {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #00AEEF;
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #00AEEF, -1px 0 0 #00AEEF, 0 1px 0 #00AEEF, 0 -1px 0 #00AEEF;
}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, this did not change the span:before. I had to set it as span.icon.major.alt:before and it worked like a charm! Thank you so much!